# Sorting a char**

Tags: c++

so I'm creating an indexer for a project and we have to use a char** to store the words from a file. I'm trying to sort the words inside the array. Heres what I've tried so far:

```
void Word::arrangeWords(char **&words)
{

char **temp=new char*[getSize()];

temp[getSize()-1]=words[getSize()-1];
for (int i=getSize()-1;i>0;i--)
{
    comp=strcmp(temp[i], temp[i-1]);
    if (comp<0)
    {
        temp[i]=words[i-1];
        temp[i-1]=words[i];
    }
    else
    {
        temp[i]=words[i];
    }
}
delete [] words;
words=temp;
}
```

this ends up not working and I kind of understand why. 
Is the an easier way to sort it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use `qsort`, or better for C++ `std::sort`.

Comment: You can make your life a lot simpler by using `std::vector<std::string>& words` and then just using `std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to sort 0-terminated strings in C++:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
void sortcstrings(const char** arr, size_t n) {
    std::sort(arr, arr+n, [](const char* a, const char* b){
        return std::strcmp(a, b)<0;});
}
```

Though using `std::string` (and `std::vector` for storing them all) makes everything just work, and is far less error-prone.